# Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main JAVAFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Under Java Build Path Libraries under the properties of my project, I have my User Library called javafx12 under Modulepath.

[image]

This removed all the errors regarding import javafx not resolved.

When I try to run my project, I get

"Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application"

How do I get rid of this error?

I am using Java SE 12 aka JDK 12.

I am using eclipse as well.

[image]

```
    package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

No errors in the class file.

Comment: Hi @Bob! Can you please post the main class in this application? Or can you tell me where is the class javafx.application.Application since that is what the compiler is complaining about. I see all other javafx.XXX.XXX jar's here. Also try searching on [https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ ]. This has clear explanation on starting up with Java FX 12 and eclipse.

Comment: @Ashish, posting it now!

Answer (score 11):

Following @Ashish link openjfx.io/openjfx-docs

I did the following and it fixed the error:

3. Add VM arguments
   To solve the issue, click on Run -> Run Configurations...  -> Java Application, create a new launch configuration for your project named `hellofx` and add these VM arguments:

Linux/Mac
Windows

--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
Warning: Make sure the option:

Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT
is not selected.
VM arguments Click apply and close the dialog.

Comment: Thanks Bob!! Glad I was able to be of some help. Also, your class name was Main. That could also have been an issue, I think. Any ways, since you solved the problem, that is a non-issue now.

Comment: Unrecognized option: --module-path
this is what I got after applying

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me after getting the error:

> Could not find or load main class application.Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.Main 
>   while trying to use JavaFX in Eclipse

1. Run then run configurations
2. In Main, choose the correct Project and Main class names
3. In Argument, enter this in VM arguments box:
   `--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`
4. Apply

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this problem.

Step #1:

- Create new file "module-info.java" like in this picture:
  [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7eh4.png)

Step #2

- Content of the "module-info.java" file should look like this:

```
module Example {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    
    opens application;
}
```