# I can't run JavaFX window despite that I add libraries and add PATH to VM options

Tags: java, javafx, path

I would like to run JavaFX. I already ran it, but I used same scenery so I don't know why it isn't running now. At first I add libraries to cart Libraries [in Module settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKDoZ.png), next I wrote path to VM options in Run/Debug configuration:

`--module-path C:\Program Files\openjfx-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

However, now I see:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\openjfx-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\openjfx-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib
```

I ran it using the same method in the past so I don't know why there is error now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main JAVAFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622327/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-application-main-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it now :-)
I forgot to write the path in quotation marks.
So this is right: 
*--module-path "C:\Program Files\openjfx-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml*